# Cannot understand why variable i is set to zero?

Tags: c

I cannot understand why `i` is set to `0` right after `array` is initialized to zero.

The program is working fine because I have `reinitialized` `value of k` to `i`.
But I could not find out why `i` becomes `0`.
And why `memset()` is clearing the array, or setting the array to `0`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    long long int i = 123456789;
    long long int j = 987654321;
    long long int cnt = 0;
    int array[9] ;
    int xyz, k, x, rem, se;
    xyz = 0;

 //   printf("I = %llf", i);
    for (i; (i < j) && (cnt < 100000); i++)
    {
        k = i;
        x = 0;
        for (se = 0; se <= 9; se++)
        {
            array[se] = 0;
        }

/*************************************************/

        i = k;   // Here i becomes zero. Why?

/************************************************/

        //memset(array, 0, 9);   

        while(k != 0)
        {
            rem = k % 10;
            for(se = 0; se <= 9; se++)
            {
                if(rem == array[se])
                {
                    xyz = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(rem == array[se])
                {
                    xyz = 1;
                    break;
                }
            array[x++] = rem;
            k = k / 10;
        }
        if (xyz != 1)
        {
            cnt++;
        //    printf("Cnt = %d  ", cnt);
        //    printf("The value i is = %lld\n", i);
        //    Sleep(10);
        }
        xyz = 0;
        // printf("The value i is = %lld\n", i);
        // printf("Cnt = %d  \n", cnt);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    printf("The value i is = %lld \n", i-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flushing `stdin` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `array` has 9 internal positions, and you're accessing 10: 0..9 (inclusive). Then, you access also `array[x]`, whith `x` not being bound...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow; since the buffer is on the stack, it might be regarded as a form of Stack Overflow<sup>†</sup>.

```
int array[9];    // Elements array[0] .. array[8]
...

for (se = 0; se <= 9; se++)
{
    array[se] = 0;
}
```

It must be `k` that is being overwritten with the extra 0; `i` is assigned 0 because that's the value in `k`.  You invoke 'undefined behaviour' when you write outside the boundaries of an array, as you did here.  Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen and it is OK.  Sometimes, it will seem to work; sometimes, there'll be unexpected side effects.  Avoid 'undefined behaviour' at all costs.

The idiomatic `for` loop is:

```
for (se = 0; se < 9; se++)
    array[se] = 0;
```

Note the `<` instead of `<=`.

<sup>†</sup> *There are those who would disagree.  See the comments.*

---

You also ask about the (commented out) call to `memset()`:

```
//memset(array, 0, 9);
```

The third parameter to `memset()` is the size in bytes of the area of memory to be set.  You are setting 9 bytes out of a total of (probably) 36 in the array, which is unlikely to be what you wanted.

Here, the array is defined in the same function so it is safe and sensible to write:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

If `array` was a parameter passed to a function, that would not work correctly; you would need a different size.  For example:

```
void somefunc(int array[], int num)
{
    ...
    memset(array, 0, num * sizeof(array[0]));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok suppose your explanation is accepted but still why i becomes 0? you mean to say array[9] is nothing but value of x?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak The array is indexed out of bounds, and the behaviour is undefined. (in this case i is altered beyond recognition)

Comment: There is no element `array[9]`; the valid array indexes are `0`, `1`, .. `8` (one less than the dimension of the array).  C is not BASIC!  There are 9 integers in the array; the first is `array[0]`, the second is `array[1]`, the eighth is `array[7]`, the ninth and final is `array[8]`.  When you access `array[9]`, you are accessing memory outside the array; memory that is **not** a part of the array.  `i` is given the value `0` because `k` has the value `0`.  It must be that on your machine with your compiler, `k` is stored immediately after array.  But that is fortuitous; do not rely on it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thnaks for your answer. My doubts got cleared.

Comment: Note that you are lucky it was not `se` that was immediately after `array`; if it was, you'd still be waiting for the loop to finish (or you'd have interrupted your program).

Comment: overflowing a stack-allocated buffer is not a stack overflow per common definition: a stack overflow happens when the call stack overflows due to allocating too many (eg via recursion) or too large (eg via stack-allocating large buffers) call frames; a stack buffer overflow is known as stack smashing

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the end of the array.

```
int array[9] ;

for(se = 0; se <= 9; se++)
{
    array[se] = 0;
}
```

In C, arrays are indexed from 0, so the loop goes one step to far. The idiomatic syntax is:

```
for(se = 0; se < 9; se++)
```

In other words, use `<` with the number of elements as the value. Often written to remove the scary numerical constant, like so:

```
for(se = 0; se < sizeof array / sizeof *array; se++)
```

This uses the `sizeof` operator to automatically (at compile-time) compute the proper number of elements, so that if you change the `array` definition the loop *remains correct*.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check this is to check the pointer of x and array[9] by printing **&x** and **&array[9]**.

If they are same, you are surely overwriting as mentioned.

Comment: Yes definitely I will try this now. You are absolutely right.